# td size does not increase when i increase the size of image

Tags: javascript, html

i want to know how to increase the size of td in table when i increase the image size.

i have image in table td.

i have some option for increase the image size,

in that time, the image will increase but the td size does not increase, so i cant see the image full size the left side will not show.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the normal case, the `td` element will expand if it can to accommodate its contents ([example](http://jsbin.com/ixage3)), but if you're out of room (the other cells can't be made smaller), you may run into a problem. Also, if you've made the `td` element a fixed size, that may take precedence. Your first task will be to identify *why* it isn't growing automatically, since that's the normal behavior.